# Button to go to ios/android phone settings screens for Cordova / HTML5 mobile app

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, cordova

We would like to create a clickable button/link in a Cordova mobile app for iOS and Android that allows the user to go directly to the phone's settings screen, ideally in either iOS or Android, so that they can easily find and enable any disabled permissions for our app.  This is especially relevant for less tech-savvy users who may not know how to find their phones settings.  If possible, even better if this button/link can take the user directly to the settings relevant to our app (eg if user did not enable something in settings).  Also, even better if this can be done using html5/js, and without using native code, or if native code is required then using a Cordova plugin for the purpose.
Have seen apps that do this -- not sure how.

Thanks

Comment: I hope this solves ur issue. Use the below plugin [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-opensettings)  & after adding this plugin   paste this below code to a function

Comment: `function settings() {
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.settings) {
        navigator.notification.alert('openSettingsTest is active');
        window.cordova.plugins.settings.open("settings",
          function () {
              window.plugins.toast.showLongBottom('Settings Opened');
          },
          function () {
              window.plugins.toast.showLongBottom('failed to open settings');
          }
        );
    } else {
        window.plugins.toast.showLongBottom('openSettingsTest is not active!');
    }
} `  and call it from a button click

Comment: You might want to check out [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin), which not only enables you to open the settings page, but also to check and modify settings from within the app.